# Recursively find files in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have run the following code which just searches for the current folder

```
for file in os.listdir("/folder/test"):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'text*'):
        print file
```

How do I search for all sub folders as well ?

Comment: Check [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) like this

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/folder/test"):
    for file in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'text*'):
            print file
```

If you just want to get all the files,

```
from os import walk, path
from fnmatch import fnmatch
[path.join(dpath, file) for dpath, _, files in os.walk("/folder/test") for file in files if fnmatch(file, 'text*')]
```